# How to add a new member to a MS Team using the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am trying to add a new member to a MS Team, but I cannot get it to work.

It adds the new member to the group, but that's where it stops. It does not add the member to the team object.

This is what I am doing:

POST to `'groups/' + groupId + '/members/$ref'` with the right data.

There is no error. It updates the group with the new member, but when I check the team, the new member is not there. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you trying to add member on your O365 group ? Onprem or Cloud ?

Comment: This is  because the group and team has different roasters. It takes some time sync users from group to the team.  Could you please check if it's updated now?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I have deleted the previous teams that I had created, so will have to try again later on a new team. When you say it takes some time, is it minutes, hours, days?

Comment: I have tested this a few times again, and the sync you refer to never happens. 

In the group, the new member appears instantaneously, but the team  never gets the update.

Comment: Could you please try it using beta API once?

Comment: Could you please share the latest request/response where it's taking time to sync?

Comment: I am posting to 

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{teamId}/members/$ref`

with this data:

`{"@odata.id":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userEmail}"}`

and I get a 204 response code.

The new user {userEmail} gets added to the group but not the team. Does not matter if I use v1.0 or the beta API, the result is the same.

The problem is not that there is a delay in the member being added to the team. The problem is that the member never gets added to the team.

Comment: Could you please try passing following JSON which is present in [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request)? Pass DirectoryObjectId instead of email Id. 

`{
  "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}"
}`

Answer (score 0):

Adding user by email alias is still not supported. Requesting you to try passing following JSON which is present in API documentation?

Pass DirectoryObjectId instead of email Id:

```
{ "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{id}" }
```